# Writing the event handlers for next button onclick for datatable in an angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, angular-datatables

I am trying to write an event handler for page change in a datatable. following is the existing code.. the libraries are included in a baselayout for following code..

**DefaultView.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pageheading">
        <h1>
            <small>AMS Default</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table dt-options="dtOptions" datatable dt-columns="dtColumns"
               class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section CommonScripts{
    <script src="~/Angular/Areas/Common/Controllers/DefaultController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Angular/Areas/Common/Services/DefaultService.js"></script>
}
```

**Defaultcontroller.js**

```
    AMSApp.controller('DefaultController', ['$rootScope', 'DefaultService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',

        function ($rootScope, DefaultService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        var self = this;

        this.Users = {};

        this.GetAllUsers = function () {
            $rootScope.CloseAlerts();

            DefaultService.GetAllUsers().success(function (result) {
                self.Users = result;
                self.loadd();
            }).catch(function (error) {
                $rootScope.ErrorMsg = "OOPS some thing went wrong. Please try again.";
            });
        }

        this.GetAllUsers();

        this.loadd = function () {
            $rootScope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('DisplayName').withTitle('UserName'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('IsSNA').withTitle('IsSNA'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('IsAdmin').withTitle('IsAdmin'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('IsDownloadPermitted').withTitle('DownloadPermitted')
            ];

            $rootScope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('data', self.Users)
            .withDisplayLength(10);
        }



    }]);

    /*

    Button Click handler:

        $("#customerSearchButton").on("click", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "",
                type: "post",
                data: { searchText: searchText }
            }).done(function (result) {
                Table.clear().draw();
                Table.rows.add(result).draw();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // needs to implement if it fails
            });
        }

    */
```

**DefaultService.js**

```
AMSApp.service('DefaultService', function ($http) {
    this.GetAllUsers = function () {
        return $http.get('/Common/User/GetAllUsers');
    }
});
```

I tried several versions like in the above-commented code.. but I need something like following in the controller.

```
/*need something like this*/
            DTOptionsBuilder.on('page.dt', function () {
                var info = table.page.info();
                console.log("hey i got eexecuted");
                $('#pageInfo').html('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
            });
```

firstly is it possible? - if not what are other alternatives?

Note: I prefer not to give an id to the table.

Comment: I tried adding `.withoptions('page.dt', callback)` . - But that doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [AngularJS jqLite API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite). Adding event listeners and creating DOM are better done inside a directive using the built-in jQuery API. This will aviod conflict with DOM manipulation by core AngularJS directives.

Comment: Also consider using [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) -- AngularJS directives that wrap jQuery Datatables.